# Cannot empty trash in OS X

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I cannot seem to empty the Trash in OS X. I can open the Trash folder and view the items, but somehow cannot empty (or even secure empty) trash. Is there any way out?

The following dialog seems to run forever. I tried restarting, but it doesn't help.

[image: Image of the "Emptying the Trash…" window with an empty progress bar and 70 items to delete.]

Answer (score 3):

Try using Disk Utility to do a "Repair Disk" to eliminate volume data structure corruption as a possible source of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try Terminal command `rm -Rf ~/.Trash/*`

Comment: If this doesn't work, run it with `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

See if there's an app using a file in .Trash using `lsof`

```
$ lsof | grep Trash
```

Close open files and/or quit the apps holding open files in .Trash.

Answer (score 0):

This [Trash It](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8214/trash-it) app has worked every time for me. It's really quite brilliant and super simple to use.